# I want the created h3 to each contain a different sentence, however if you click the same h3 it should give the same sentence (Per page load of course

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

**Please excuse the use of var**, it is part of the challenge and is **intended to help me learn about closure**. Currently, the code gives all 100 h3's the same sentence. I've tried moving the randomName, randomWeapon, and randomLocation variables into the addEvent function. When I do this I assign the same h3 a new sentence on every click. I'm guessing  I need to use .call or .apply, but I am new to functions, and internet tutorials just aren't getting me there.

```
    <script>names = ['Alex', 'Ben', 'Dr.Modi', 'Nick', 'Jason'];
    locations = ['Loc1', 'Loc2', 'Loc3', 'Loc4', 'Loc5', 'Loc6', 'Loc7', 'Loc8', 'Loc9', 'Loc10'];
    weapons = ['knife', 'stool', 'plunger', 'wax', 'poison', 'arthritis', 'spider', 'sword', 'meth', 'broken-bottle', 'dog', 'panda', 'string', 'tazer', 'gun', 'bullet', '17', 'dumbell', 'kricket', 'spear'];
    const body = document.body;
    var i = 1
    
    
       
    
        var myFunc = () => {
    
            var makeAqu = $(body).append('<h3 id=acu' + i + ' style="cursor: pointer;"> Accusation' + i + '</h3>');
            makeAqu;
            
            var randomName = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
            var randomLocation = locations[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
            var randomWeapon = weapons[Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)];
    
    
            function addEvent(e) {
                makeAqu.on("click", () => {
                    
            
                    
                    
                    alert(`I accuse ${randomName}, with the ${randomWeapon} in the ${randomLocation}!`);
    
                    e.preventDefault();
    
                })
            }
             return addEvent();
        }
    
        do {
        myFunc();
    
        i++;
    } while (i < 101);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `addEvent` bind the `click` hander on the `body` and not on the `h3`. And the second is that you do `e.preventDefault` when you have not defined `e` (*you should set it on the `click` handler,not the `addEvent` function*) which causes an error and stops the execution.

If you had fixed the `e` issue, you would see that when you click on an `h3` you get all 100 alerts.

Try changing

```
var makeAqu = $(body).append('<h3 id=acu' + i + ' style="cursor: pointer;"> Accusation' + i + '</h3>');
```

to

```
var makeAqu = $('<h3 id=acu' + i + ' style="cursor: pointer;"> Accusation' + i + '</h3>');
$(body).append(makeAqu);
```

Comment: Thank you much! If you don't mind, could you please explain what it is about the first example that makes the click handler bind to the body?

Comment: @Wayne In general jquery methods return the original object (*to allow for chaining methods*), with a few exceptions for the traversing type of methods (`find`,`filter`, `get` etc). You do `$(body)` and then start the chaining so that is what will be returned. not the appended contents. In the code i posted the `makeAqu` only holds the created `h3` element so you can start binding to it.